# How to correctly parse a text file with a RegexParser?

Tags: regex, scala, parsing

I want to parse the following test data: It works for 3 case, so I think there's a problem in my regex. If a line starts with a # and has a comment that also starts with a # it stops working. Can someone explain why? Here's my solution so far...

```
val testDate =
  """
    |127.0.0.1 ads234.com
    |#127.0.0.1 auto.search.msn.com  # Microsoft uses this server to redirect
    |#127.0.0.1 sitefinder.verisign.com # Verisign has joined the game
    |#127.0.0.1 sitefinder-idn.verisign.com # of trying to hijack mistyped
    |#127.0.0.1 s0.2mdn.net     # This may interfere with some streaming
    |#127.0.0.1 ad.doubleclick.net   # This may interfere with www.sears.com
    |127.0.0.1 media.fastclick.net  # Likewise, this may interfere with some
    |127.0.0.1 cdn.fastclick.net
  """.stripMargin
```

I want to keep the # and the comment if there's any.

```
object Example extends RegexParsers {
  def comment: Parser[String] = """#.*""".r
  def url: Parser[String] = """[A-Za-z0-9-\.\_\-]{1,65}(?<!-)\.+[A-Za-z]{2,7}""".r
  def localhost: Parser[String] = """\b(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\b""".r
  def pound: Parser[String] = "#".r
  def port: Parser[String] = """:\d{3}""".r

  def urlPort = url | url <~ port

  def pos1 = localhost ~ urlPort ^^ {
    case _ ~ dns => LineParsed("", dns, "")
  }
  def pos2 = pound ~ localhost ~ urlPort ^^ {
    case p ~ _ ~ dns => LineParsed(p, dns, "")
  }
  def pos3 = localhost ~ urlPort ~ comment ^^ {
    case _ ~ dns ~ com => LineParsed("", dns, com)
  }
  def pos4 =enter code here pound ~ localhost ~ urlPort ~ comment ^^ {
    case p ~ _ ~ dns ~ com => LineParsed(p, dns, com)
  }

  def linePos = pos1 | pos2 | pos3 | pos4

  def fullLine = repsep(linePos, """\W*""".r)
}
```

Got the following exception:

```
#127.0.0.1 auto.search.msn.com  # Microsoft uses this server to redirect

                                  ^
    java.lang.RuntimeException: No result when parsing failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in your code. First, by default newline characters are counted as whitespaces, but you need to "see" them to break entries correctly. So you need to redefine whitespaces:

```
object Example extends RegexParsers {
   override protected val whiteSpace: Regex = "[ \t]+".r
```

The `fullLine` parser is then written as:

```
   //allow several empty lines at the beginning and between entries
   def fullLine = rep("\n") ~> repsep(linePos, rep1("\n"))
```

(Another option would be to split the line beforehand and parse them individually)

The next mistake is the way you combine parsers with `|`. To parse `A` optionally followed by `B`, don't write `A | A ~ B`. It will never try to read a `B` after reading a `A` because the left hand side is already a success. Write instead: `A ~ B.?`

```
  def urlPort = url <~ port.?  // But anyway, you'll neve have a port in a host file !
```

In the same way, the 4 cases `pos1 | pos2 | pos3 | pos4` can be much simplified:

```
  def linePos = pound.? ~ localhost ~ urlPort ~ comment.? ^^ {
     case p ~ _ ~ dns ~ com  ⇒ LineParsed(p.getOrElse(""), dns,com.getOrElse(""))
  }
```

You can see here how the `?` combinator gives you back an `Option` for `p` and `com`. I use `getOrElse` to fit in the structure of `LineParsed` and keep the original behaviour of your code, but a much more scala-ish approach would be to keep it as an option in the `LineParsed` class.

Here is the final working code that parses your example:

```
object Example extends RegexParsers {
  override protected val whiteSpace: Regex = "[ \t]+".r
  def comment: Parser[String] = """#.*""".r
  def url: Parser[String] = """[A-Za-z0-9-\.\_\-]{1,65}(?<!-)\.+[A-Za-z]{2,7}""".r
  def localhost: Parser[String] = """\b(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\b""".r
  def pound: Parser[String] = "#".r
  def port: Parser[String] = """:\d{3}""".r
  def urlPort = url <~ port.?

  def linePos = pound.? ~ localhost ~ urlPort ~ comment.? ^^ {
    case p ~ _ ~ dns ~ com  ⇒ LineParsed(p.getOrElse(""), dns, com.getOrElse(""))
  }

  def fullLine = rep("\n") ~> repsep(linePos, rep1("\n"))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I tried to run the improved code but now I get an Exception saying "[10.3] failure: string matching regex `\b(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\b' expected but end of source found".

Comment: use `parse` instead of `parseAll`, or allow empty lines at the end of the fullLine parser